# from hello_qiskit import run_puzzle results in error

Tags: qiskit, programming, textbook-and-exercises

I am working my way through the beta version of the Qiskit textbook.

Everything was going fine until I got to the Visualizing Entanglement section and had some exercises to complete.

All of the exercises rely on the `hello_qiskit` package which doesn't seem available.

I have also tried running the exercises in the IBM Quantum Lab but it resulted in similar issues.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_426/3330317747.py", line 1, in <module>
    from hello_qiskit import run_puzzle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello_qiskit'

Use %tb to get the full traceback.
```

Comment: Where are you running it from? It seems to work for me on [here](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/visualizing-entanglement)

Comment: It's working for me as well now!